# Charset independent String equals, hashcode and compare

Tags: java, string

How to obtain the charset independent String operations: equals, hashcode and compare?

e.g.:

```
assertEquals("1ª", new String(new byte[] { (byte) '1', (byte) 166 }, "ISO-8859-15"));
```

This is an example of the fail.

**UPDATE**

String methods already are charset-independent. My mistake was that 166 is the char ª in the standard extended ASCII table, but not in the ISO-8859-15 charset. In this one the ª corresponds to the 170.

Comment: convert to some byte array using some common "superior" charset??

Comment: "extended ASCII" is not a real thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the `ª` character in the `"1ª"` Java String literal is some character that has been mangled due to an incorrect character decoding somewhere along the line.  I'm guessing that it is *supposed* to be the same character that what 166 represents.

If you want to avoid problems like that when you embed string literals in ISO-Java source code, then the solution is to use Unicode escapes.  For example:

```
assertEquals("1\u0160", new String(new byte[] { (byte) '1', (byte) 166 },
                              ISO-8859-15"));
```

Unicode codepoint U+0160 is `š` ... which corresponds to code 166 (decimal) in ISO-8859-15.  The `\u....` syntax in Java source code is independent of the charset that the source is encoded in.

(Please excuse me if I've got the actual characters incorrect.  The general approach is sound though.)